# ignite web-console "this.errors$.filter(...).take(...).map is not a function"

Tags: ignite

setup:

- ignite node is running ok
- backend module is running ok

  > Start listening on 127.0.0.1:3000
- frontend module is running ok

  > Project is running at http://127.0.0.1:9000/
- web-agent running ok

  > Connection successfully established to cluster with nodes: [1577D6FF]

error:

- can not fetch cache meta
- TypeError: this.errors$.filter(...).take(...).map is not a function
  at SimpleWorkerPool.postMessage (SimpleWorkerPool.js:114), as below:

[error image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB7CS.png)

Comment: ignite version:  2.3.0

Answer (score 2):

There a bug in modules/web-console/frontend/app/utils/SimpleWorkerPool.js

To fix you need to add missing import:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

And rebuild frontend.

This is already fixed in master.